# How to uninstall mongodb on arch linux?

Tags: mongodb, archlinux

I have install mongodb but isnt working, so i wan to remove it, but i dont know how to doit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0cCc.png)

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://www.positronx.io/how-to-completely-uninstall-mongodb-from-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command to uninstall mongodb-bin from Arch

```
sudo pacman -R mongodb-bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).